# Convert from auto_ptr to normal pointer

Tags: c++, stl, auto-ptr

I have some third party libraries that generate and return an auto_ptr. However, I really want  to use some STL containers.

So I'm guessing one way would be to convert

```
auto_ptr <int> ptr = some_library_call ();
```

into a regular c++ pointer. Will the following work?

```
int* myptr = ptr;
```

If not, what is the best way to use STL with auto_ptr (yes I know it won't work directly... I'm aware that stl and auto_ptr don't mix together)?

Comment: What does the 3rd party function do, and how are you using the return value with STL?

Comment: Basically reads some stuff from a file and deserialize it. So it's actually some_library_call (string filename) if that helps...

Comment: Note that `std::unique_ptr<>` has a conversion constructor that takes a `std::auto_ptr<>`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use either `ptr.get()` if you want to obtain the pointer and still let the  `auto_ptr` to delete it afterwards, or use `ptr.release()` to obtain the pointer and make the `auto_ptr` forget about it (you have to delete it afterwards.)

Answer (score 4):

Call [release() on the auto_ptr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/memory/auto_ptr/release/), then you can store the value in a different smart pointer or raw pointer and use it with STL containers.